# Getting error in Composer setup

Tags: php, web-services, rest, composer-php

I am installing Composer software in my system, but it is showing given below error. Please suggest a solution.

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server. 
>   failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.

Comment: Is there any firewall on your computer or network?

Comment: There is no firewall in my computer .

Comment: Run `composer diag` and post the output into your question (edit it), please.